# String.Format in .NET

Tags: .net, string-formatting

I have a little problem on the string formatting in .NET

```
?String.Format("{00} {1}", 1, "min")
"1 min"
```

I need the output "01 min" but "20 min" if instead the 1 I have 20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using "00" as if it's the format specifier, but it's actually just the *index* part of the format item. You want:

```
String.Format("{0:00} {1}", 1, "min")
```

So within `{0:00}` the first part (`0`) is the index, and second part (`00`) is the format string. See the [MSDN page on composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/txafckwd.aspx) for more information.

Or you could use:

```
String.Format("{0:d2} {1}", 1, "min")
```

Where `d2` is a [standard numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) with 2 as the precision specifier.